# How to control spacing around the minipage

Tags: minipage

I would like to know how to put some space between my minipages and the \vrule, in this title page for an exam I am trying to produce.

If there is another way of approaching what I am trying to do I am happy to look at alternatives to minipage.

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\graphicspath{{\subfix{../images/}}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{flushright}
\begin{Huge}
2020

{\Large
My Institute

}
\vspace{1cm}
First Assessment Task
\end{Huge}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{3cm}

\fontsize{30}{50}\selectfont Software Design and 

Development
\newline\newline\newline

\Large
\vspace{5cm}
\begin{minipage}{6.5cm}

\textbf{General Instructions}
\begin{itemize}

    \item Reading time - 5 minutes
    
    \item Working time - 1 hour
    
    \item Write using blue or black pen
    
    \item Write your student number and / or name at the top of every page
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\vrule
\begin{minipage}{6cm}

\large{\textbf{Total Marks:90 }}
\normalsize
\newline\newline
\large{\textbf{Section I}}

Total marks (10)
\begin{itemize}

    \item Attempt Questions 1 - 10
    
    \item Allow about 12 minutes for this section
    
    \item Mark your answers on the answer sheet provided
    
\end{itemize}
\large{\textbf{Section II}}

Total marks (30)
\begin{itemize}
    \item Attempt Questions 1 - 10
    \item Allow about 12 minutes for this section
    \item Mark your answers on the answer sheet provided
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\large{\textbf{Total Marks:90 }}\normalsize` is a slightly weird markup `\textbf{\large Total Marks:90 }`  would be simpler , size commands do not take an argument

Comment: Just put some spacing commands before and after the `\vrule`, for example `~\vrule~` or `\quad\vrule\quad` or use some `\hspace{....}`